# Why is the rep shown next to the user on the question list?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, homepage

My last question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202310/filter-the-questions-to-those-from-users-with-x-rep was unpopular as it discriminates the low-rep. Oddly the duplicate appears to be very popular!

Anyway, my question is now, baring that in mind:

Why the rep is so clearly presented on the question list?

It seems to me that this allows people to mentally discriminate/avoid questions that are from low-rep users.

Is there any legitimate reason for displaying the rep next to the name on this list?

Comment: Because we display rep with the user everywhere we display the user?

Comment: Because that's what reputation *is*. If people are discriminating for/against other people based on their reputation, then the very concept of reputation is at work.

Comment: @Oded Apart from in comments. Then it's a hint/tool tip.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I'm suggesting it is hidden on question list only. That isn't what rep is. You'd still see it everywhere else and still have the leagues.

Comment: Related maybe a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199394/152859

Comment: @weston I'll repeat what I said as answer to the linked question: *Because it's about the most important single stat about a user, after his/her display name* - it helps to identify the user and yes sometimes it might lead to discrimination but it's really not Stack Exchange fault.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd OK, so it's important. But do I need to see it before I answer a question is my question.

Comment: @weston consider it as clothes. Do you need to see the cloth of each and every person you meet? The answer is yes: you need to *see* but you don't have to *look*. Just ignore it; give a brief glance and don't start pondering about it. :-)

Comment: I wasn't around at that stage but I wonder if when meta was newer if upvotes on question were more of a "thanks for the suggestion"? Afterall look at the answers and add up the votes on them for and against - it seems opinion on the change itself was similar back then. Plus of course opinions will change over time anyway, you might be reading into it too far.

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday a user posted his [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19466896/1). It was about an obsolete compiler. Currently<sup>1</sup> there are 727 views and 15 up-votes for it. At one time it was near the top of the Hot Questions list.

1) So you can see there's no discrimination against first-time posters. Their questions can get read and up-voted.

2) Knowing that someone is a first-time poster can draw *positive attention* to help reformat a post so that it's more easily understood.

If there's any problem it's that the people who helped the first-time poster didn't get any rep, but **I'm sure they like helping the newbies**.

Long story short: The system works and it can work better if people spend a few minutes helping out first-time posters.

<sup>1 stats are before I posted here.</sup>

Comment: A single example of a user not being discriminated against is not proof that new users are never discriminated against.  All it shows is that new users aren't *always* discriminated against.

Comment: @servy You're exactly right. But my point is that you can take a bad question, fix it up, and help someone get rep. In other words, if you're worried about newbies -- help them -- don't hide them.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a clear difference between showing someone's reputation, and wanting to filter all of them out because "They have low rep, they probably can't ask good questions".

Rep's shown next to your name *everywhere* but comments, and some chat entries. SE is all about the imaginary internet points, isn't it?

In addition, this question is based on an incorrect premise - What the question shows is the last *post* associated with the question - by posting my posting this, MSO will show my name and reputation next to the question- and no one's going to up or downvote your question cause I answered it. The same will happen if I edit it.

Post question edit screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot after I posted a second answer to this to check (sorry!)

[image]

The name/reputation next to the question as such is just a way of seeing who was last active in the question rather than an attempt, intentional or unintentional to influence folk to vote a certain way

Your tree has no squirrel, and as such, this is not the tree you should be barking up - since *whose* name is next to a question can and will vary. That said, If you're a high rep user, and you do something stupid, it gives other users all the more reason to mock you in the comments - so.. I'd say being able to see your rep is a double edged sword.

Comment: My "incorrect premise" doesn't bare out, I just checked a few questions, they all show the question asker on the question list. Not the last activity.

Comment: That is odd, we clearly are looking at different views. I have added my view of question. I see now, you are on this view http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active I am on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: That might do it. I just use the stock homepage. Nonetheless, it shows the relativity of whose username is displayed.